# Enhancement Suggestion : Single SignOn using Google should support to choose from multiple accounts

Tags: feature-request, login, google, sign-up

When I click SignIn > Google > It is directly selecting my primary account instead of showing an option to choose from my many accounts. It is critical issue since I am having multiple accounts under gmail itself(1. College Mail, 2. Personal Mail, 3. Cooperate Mail). In the below scenario whenever I click SSO using Google it will take my college id to which my stack-overflow is not associated. So currently I am signing out and login to my personal mail first then clicking SSO again to solve the issue now. But I would recommend to show a popup to select from all the accounts for the SSO requested users.

Comment: But doesn't that defeat the purpose of SSO? You're currently signed in with Google, your account is linked, you get signed in on the SE sites. And even this functionality should exist, isn't that an issue to be solved by Google, as they seem to allow multiple accounts with one identity? I mean, if this means that my login experience gets crippled as I only have one account, I don't want this feature.

Comment: google has a multiple account/profile option. For example, my mother's google account is delegated to mine - so I can switch to her account fairly trivially. Its useful in a few other situations as well

Comment: This is common in apps, not websites, from what I've seen. Still, a "nice to have" feature, if possible.

Comment: @rene please visit the URL http://allbinginfotech.com/old/products/ and click the signin to see the feature that is solely developed by me. Its just plug-and-play interface by google. This feature will surely increase the usability of SSO in StackOverflow and Google like #ShadowWizard has mentioned.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thank you for supporting for the functionality in order to make our stack-overflow the best-in-class. Yes Wizard its possible please visit this URL allbinginfotech.com/old/products (Developed by me only for a demo of this)  to see that feature

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Sorry to tell that I didnt got exactly what's your scenario. I would like to get the issue clarified so that we can have more best-solutions

Comment: Naw. Was trying to explain to Rene what it was.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek ok

Comment: It always gives me this option already, for years?

Comment: It can be enforced by either setting `approval_prompt=force`, or `prompt=consent`, or `prompt=select_account+consent` as the authorization URL.

Comment: Does your college Google account think it has access to Stack Exchange?  Please log into that account and go to "My Account" > "Sign in and Security" > "Apps with Account Access". If you see Stack Exchange there, remove it and then see if it still defaults to that Google account instead of showing you a list.

Comment: @ThomasEaso I have had a prompt appear asking me what google account I want to use with a list of currently signed in accounts and the option to sign into another for years now.

Comment: @JoeW Now i'm also getting the prompt now. I think this issue is solved by StackOverflow team after the question is posted

Comment: @Mave Yes you are right Mave that is the solution for this issue. or else its can be like i had given in the link. Since the issue is already solved. So i think i can close this post with right answer

Comment: Thanks team for fixing the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, this is the case already (and it's more of a feature of Google than of StackExchange).

Let me show you what it looks like:

[image]

Perhaps we should troubleshoot why you're not seeing this screen?

I get this screen because starting my Stack Overflow account was pretty much the last thing I did with my old Google account.

In my case I'd prefer to update my email address then totally quit using the old Gmail account if that were an option. Otherwise I accidentally sign into the wrong account sometimes and you have to log out and log in again.

Comment: You can actually have multiple google accounts associated with a single stack exchange account so you could easily add your new google account to your existing stack exchange one and forgot about the old google account

Comment: @JoeW Oh, that sounds good! i will need to do that, thank you

Comment: Don't think it is as I am pretty sure I have been using it for a few years at least.